# How to setState on click event, only once within a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, frontend

I have a function where I am looping through a list of labels.
I have a onClick event where I am calling a function.
This function sets the state for `clicked` to that of the id of the clicked item in the loop. The function also console.log's the state.

It's logging the state of `clicked` 8 times. There are current 4 items in my loop.

How can I make it so that I can set the state to `clicked` every time the user clicks on an item in the list?

Here is my loop:

```
 {
  filteredArray.map(link => {
   return (
    <div
     key={link.id}
     role="button"
     style={{paddingBottom: 20}}
     onClick={this.changeView(link.id)}
     onKeyPress={this.changeView(link.id)}
     tabIndex={0}
    >
    <Paragraph size="large">
    <a className='heading__dropdown__link' 
     {link.label}
    </a>
    </Paragraph>
   </div>
  )
 })
}
```

Here is my function `changeView`:

```
  changeView(id) {
    const { clicked } = this.state
    console.log(clicked)

    return (
      () => this.setState({clicked: id})
    )
  }
```

Comment: You don't log when the button was clicked, but when the component renders. If it logs 8 times, it means that your component rerenderd once (and `changeView` was called 8 times) . That said, I don't get what the problem is (except that the logging is not useful)

Comment: it logged 8 times because you are calling the function 2 times for each items `onClick={this.changeView(link.id)}
     onKeyPress={this.changeView(link.id)}`, 4 items * 2 = 8

Comment: thanks, how do I make it so that it logs when the component renders? I just want to be able to set the state and log it every time an item is clicked, thus setting the state to the id of the clicked item. @oliv

Comment: `changeView` is returning a function, so the state will be updated only when you are clicking or pressing a key

Comment: if you want to `console.log` only when an item is clicked, you need to update `changeView` to `changeView(id) {
    return () => this.setState(state => {console.log(state.clicked); return {clicked: id};});
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Your calling the function for every element, set your function like so:

```
changeView = id => ev => this.setState({clicked: id});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove onPress and add arrow function in `onClick` like this

`onClick={()=>this.changeView(link.id)}`

hope this will help